# Problems when trying to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, dependencies

When I was trying to upgrade my server from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 I was facing problems with some packages. It was saying,

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
  You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      gcc-4.4: Depends: gcc-4.4-base (= 4.4.7-1ubuntu2) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
               Depends: cpp-4.4 (= 4.4.7-1ubuntu2) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
               Depends: binutils (>= 2.20.1-15~) but 2.20.1-3ubuntu7.1 is installed
               Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.4.7-1ubuntu2) but 1:4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
               Recommends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not installed
      libnih-dbus1: Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1) but 1.0.1-1 is installed
      libnih1: Depends: libc6 (< 2.12) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.5 is installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: That... and it states "You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these." in the message. When dealing with EOL releases I would suggest re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

try first

`sudo apt-get update -f`

or

`sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

then

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

then

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

hope it will work for you , if not check you broken repo's (package's)